# Issue in Akka 2.6.3 Cancellable

Tags: java, akka

I want to change below Akka classic code to Akka 2.6.3 to work my scheduler in new project.

```
Cancellable tickTaskFrontend = context().system().scheduler().schedule(Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES), Duration.create(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES), self(), "CheckFrontendInit", context().dispatcher(), null);
```

I didn't see any code for Cancellable in Akka 2.6.3.

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Cancellable.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am looking for Java code.

Comment: That is javadoc for the akka.actor.Cancellable object.  What do you think you are looking for?